# Find marginal probability distribution of $ X$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$X$ and $Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution with $\sigma_X= 5\ mL,\ \sigma_Y= 2\ mL, \ \mu_X= 120\ mL, \ \mu_Y= 100\ mL$ and $\rho = 0.6.$

How do I find the marginal probability distribution of $X$? Is there some formula to do this?

Comment: Do you know how to obtain a marginal probability distribution from a joint distribution in general?

Comment: Which kind of reference text on normal random variables do you follow?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the pair of random variables $\langle{X,Y}\rangle$ has a bivariate normal distribution, only if the (marginal) distribution of any linear combination of the variables is a univariate normal distribution.

- $X$ is a linear combination of the two random variables; witness: $X=1\cdot X+0\cdot Y$.   Thus it has a univariate normal distribution.   What do you suspect the parameters of this might be?
- $Y$ is a linear combination of the two random variables; witness: $Y=0\cdot X+1\cdot Y$.   Thus it has a univariate normal distribution.   What do you suspect the parameters of this might be?